# MVC3 Database Examples?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In Mvc3 it is necessary to use EDM or we can use normal process. if we go for normal process how can write the SqlCommand,SqlDataAdapter to conctact database. Is there any reference it is more use full.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary to use EDM, you can use an database that you wish.

As per most websites, you can develop a standard Data Access Layer that encapsulates this code and call this from your MVC controllers, or from an additional Business Logic Layer.

The actual implementation of the Data Access Layer is not detailed here and you can find many examples of approaches for this by searching SO and the internet in general.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is built **on top of ASP.Net**, so everything you used to use such as `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter` to connect to database can still be used.

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10487512/1182982)